# HTML Help Workshop - Is it possible to use CSS or JavaScript within a .CHM file?

Tags: javascript, css, chm, html-help-workshop

I'm in the process of creating .chm files and was curious to know if these options are available?

Comment: What tool do you use to generate CHM files? You may add a tag like e.g. html-help-workshop to your question or describe when asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can use CSS. JavaScript not in all cases. See [HTMLHelp - Linking](https://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_linking.htm).

Make sure your design.css is inside you project level structure and added to the [FILES] section of your HHP project file. You can open this *.hhp file with e.g. Notepad++ to add files.
If the files are listed in the [FILES] section the compiler includes them to the CHM file.

```
[FILES] 
welcome.htm 
design.css 
First_Steps\download.htm 
First_Steps\starting_program.htm 
How_to_extend\extend_menu.htm 
How_to_extend\power_function.htm 
images\gui_screenshot.jpg
```