# HTML Help Workshop - Images not being displayed

Tags: html, chm, html-help-workshop

I've been attempting to display images included in the project of my help file.

```
[FILES]
Images\About-1.png
Images\Prompt-1.png
Images\Prompt-2.png
Images\Settings-1.png
Images\Settings-2.png
Images\Settings-3.png
Images\Settings-4.png
Images\Settings-5.png
```

These are the list of images I wish to include and I reference them in my HTML files as so,

```
<div class='Image'>
                <img height='200' width='auto' src='Images\Settings-3.png'
                    alt='Settings-3' />
            </div>
```

This seems like it should work but when I compile the project to a CHM file the log says it contains no graphics and the images are not displayed.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue - code is working for me without using any CSS for images. Having a normal use case you don't need to specify all images in your *.hhp Project file. The compiler automatically fetches these images from your HTML files.

If you want, you can use wildcards in the [FILES] section to specify every 
file in a given directory. For example:

```
[FILES]
welcome.htm
settings\Setting-1.htm
settings\Setting-2.htm
images\*.png
css\foobar.css
```

Think about a CHM as a zipped web page. So prepare all your help content files as a structured web in a local drive like shown above. Please note, your *.HHP project file must be stored in the root folder where  e.g. welcome.htm resides.

Check and delete four blank in the `[FILES]` line - mabe a typo here only. If yes edit your question.

Please remove `class='Image'` from HTML, check your class and make sure your CSS was added. Follow the hints from [HTML Help Workshop - Is it possible to use CSS or JavaScript within a .CHM file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942102/is-it-possible-to-use-css-or-javascript-within-a-chm-file)

Comment: I've used the wildcard and now one photo in settings.htm is appearing, also I've edited my question due to the typo.

Comment: Interestingly I've discovered the issue, the height and width attribute once removed allow the pictures to be displayed, however this is still an issue as I need them sized appropriately.

Comment: @benbants: I checked this on a second machine with Microsoft Windows10 - Edge and of course the required Internet Explorer installed - no issue seen. A test images is sized appropriately from 323 px to a height of 200 px. Something wrong in your CSS class='Image'?

Comment: I haven't added the css to the help file as of yet so I don't think that'd be causing the issue?

Comment: Implemented my css file and images are now displaying correctly.

Comment: @benbants: Great!